# Wrong drag and drop location NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I am trying to reorder cells based on drag-and-drop activity by the user. It seems I can only make it work one way, either it works when the dragged cell is below the drop position OR it works when the dragged cell is above the drop location.

e.g: if I put # 1 between 3 and 4, i'd have: [2,3,4,1,5,6..]. If I put #6 between 3 and 4 it works. [1,2,3,6,4,5...]

Can somebody point out what I might be doing wrong?

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, acceptDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, row: Int, dropOperation: NSTableViewDropOperation) -> Bool {

    let data: NSData = info.draggingPasteboard().dataForType(NSGeneralPboard)!
    let rowIndexes: NSIndexSet = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! NSIndexSet
    let value: NSImage = images[rowIndexes.firstIndex]
    let sValue: String = numbers[rowIndexes.firstIndex]

    numbers.removeAtIndex(rowIndexes.firstIndex)
    images.removeAtIndex(rowIndexes.firstIndex)
    if (row > images.count)
    {
        numbers.insert(sValue, atIndex: row - 1)
        images.insert(value, atIndex: row - 1)
    } else {
        numbers.insert(sValue, atIndex: row)
        images.insert(value, atIndex: row)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
    return true
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happens to the rows below the dropped row, do they stay at the same index?

Comment: Yes, if I put # 1 between 3 and 4, i'd have: [2,3,4,1,5,6..]. If I put #6 between 3 and 4 it works. [1,2,3,6,4,5...]

Comment: If you have [0,1,2,3,4] and remove 2, it becomes [0,1,3,4]. If you want to insert 2 at original index 4, you have to insert at index 3. So if row > rowIndexes.firstIndex, insert at row - 1.